# how to find sentry issue by event id or custom Raven.user_context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry, raven

In my system, when users see program error (status is 500), they can write details in feedback form and submit it.

```
# for sentry
Raven.user_context sentry_uid: SecureRandom.uuid
```

and

```
-# feedback form
- form_for @feedback do |form|
  = input :sentry_uid
```

Question is: How to find sentry issue by sentry_uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont support searching by arbitrary values, but what you can do is:

- Use tags_context to bind 'sentry_uid'
- Use user_context.id (or similar) to bind a real user ID

Once either of those are done, you can use either 'sentry_uid:foo' or 'user.id:foo' in the search query.